# Using Angular 8, how to get a reference to a DOM element that loads several seconds after the rest of the page?

Tags: angular, getelementbyid

I am writing an app for a client using Angular 8. The app uses a cloud service from ESRI that serves as an address lookup textbox (very similar to the one that Google does that everyone is familiar with).

Here is the problem I can't seem to figure out how to solve.

When the javascript is called, ESRI provides it's own interface element by inserting a textbox and other code into the page. I need to get a handle to that element, because it raises an event when an address is found, and I need to be able to respond to that event.

Since the element is being downloaded from the web and added to the page "after the fact", it takes a few seconds for the textbox to appear on the page. How long it takes depends on the speed of the connection, etc.

When I do a "document.getElementById()" call, it fails, because the element doesn't yet exist. I have tried putting the getElementById() call in the AfterViewInit() but that's still occurring before the textbox appears.

Is there some way to know when the external element has loaded and is ready for access?

Comment: Could you show us some code? From my initial thoughts, if you're making an async call then you should be able to subscribe to the observable (.then on a promise) which will resolve after?

Comment: If you are using a script loader for the ESRI script, can you query the DOM after the script loader resolves?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to "probe" for given element until its there waiting some amount of time between probes.

```
setElementOrWait() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        let element = docment.getElementById(id);
        if (element == null) {   //  or undefined - adjust accordingly
            setElementOrWait();
        } else {
            this.myElement=element;
        }     
    }, 500)
}
```